# Bat File Cannot Find Symbol Warnings

Tags: java, batch-file, netbeans, command-line

I am using a .bat file that converts .java files into .xml files through the command line. While it does its job it gives me a warning for the class EMeasure. In fact, there are 100 of these warnings total. An example of these errors is as follows:

```
  symbol:    class EMEasure
  location:  class CPDA
CPDA.java: 992: error: cannot find symbol
  public static EMeasure computeDFL(EMeasure dFLOFP, EMeausre fP){
```

I'd like to also make mention that the program works just fine on NetBeans even though it outputs "error" on the command line.

Comment: Well, what's on line 992?

Comment: A declarations of EMeasure. Like I said, there are no errors in NetBeans. This only happens in the command line even though the .java file contains the necessary imports.

Comment: Apparently this application also compiles said .java files? As what you post is a compile error, not a warning of any kind. A valid compile error too, given that there is a typo in there ("EMeausre").

Answer (score 0):

Your converting-tool obviously also compiles the java classes.
If you get compile errors in Tool B but not in Tool A, then the most probable cause is a not properly set classpath in Tool B.
  So check the classpath in your converting-tool.
May be a simply a SET CLASSPATH= ....  order in yout batchfile.